# Ghost podcasts appearing on smart playlist

Tags: itunes, podcasts, smart-playlist

When I create a smart playlist that should only have podcasts, a "ghost" podcasts appear then disappears when I am updating my podcasts subscriptions. I've tried downloading the podcast again and then deleting it, but it keeps coming back. I've also searched through my library, and these podcasts do no t exists. Please note that I am not using the Podcasts app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had been using the Podcast app, and then deleted it. I believe this left orphaned podcast episodes in the phone itself. I had to SSH into the phone and delete the orphaned files. I found this out when I switched to manually managing my music, and the "ghost" podcasts appeared on the phone (but not iTunes).

I had earlier attempted re-downloading the Podcast app and re-downloading the "ghost" podcasts, but that didn't solve it.